# Terraform scripts throw " Invalid AWS Region: {var.AWS_REGION}"

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

when I run "terraform apply" I am getting the following error. I made sure my AMI is in us-west-1 region.
not sure what else could be the problem

PS C:\terraform> terraform apply

Error: Invalid AWS Region: {var.AWS_REGION}

terraform.tfvars file

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY="zzz"
AWS_SECRET_KEY="zzz"
```

provider.tf file

```
  provider "aws"{
  access_key = "{var.AWS_ACCESS_KEY}"
  secret_key = "{var.AWS_SECRECT_KEY}"
  region = "{var.AWS_REGION}"
 }
```

vars.tf file

```
   variable "AWS_ACCESS_KEY" {}
   variable "AWS_SECRET_KEY" {}
   variable "AWS_REGION" {
       default = "us-west-1"
    }
   variable "AMIS"{
   type = map(string)
   default ={
        us-west-1 = "ami-0948be9af4ee55d19"
    }
}
```

instance.tf

```
    resource "aws_instance" "example"{
    ami = "lookup(var.AMIS,var.AWS_REGION)"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are literally passing the strings "{var.AWS_ACCESS_KEY}" "{var.AWS_SECRET_KEY}" and "{var.AWS_REGION}" to the provider

Try this if you are using terraform 12+:

```
provider "aws"{
   access_key = var.AWS_ACCESS_KEY
   secret_key = var.AWS_SECRET_KEY
   region = var.AWS_REGION
}
```

if you are using terraform older than 0.12 then it should be set like this using the $ sign.

```
provider "aws"{
   access_key = ${var.AWS_ACCESS_KEY} 
   secret_key = ${var.AWS_SECRET_KEY} 
   region = ${var.AWS_REGION} 
}
```

Comment: I have version 0.14.4 when I tried your suggestion, says                                               
           Error: Reference to undeclared input variable  on provider.tf line 3, in provider "aws":
          3:    secret_key = var.AWS_SECRECT_KEY

                 An input variable with the name "AWS_SECRECT_KEY" has not been 
                declared. Did you mean "AWS_SECRET_KEY"?

Comment: I actually copied/pasted the variable names from your initial post (provider.tf). The typo comes from here (I fixed the answer) but obviously it's AWS_SECRET_KEY. If you are using 0.14, that's the way to go.

Comment: No clue whats going on. where is the typo?

Comment: Did you retry my suggestion after my last edit ?

Comment: Yeah. I tried. It diddn't work. same error